# ExtJS: How to use itemSelector for XTemplate having nested loop?

Tags: javascript, extjs, ria, extjs5

I am working on `Ext.view.View` class to create one data view for displaying list of images received after ajax proxy. As per Sencha Doc for DataView, `itemSelector` property is mandatory. So I am using it as `itemSelector: 'div.thumb-wrap'` but respective class is inside the nested loop not in the outer loop as below:
**JS code:**

```
Ext.define("DSApp.Desktop.view.ImageView",{
extend: 'Ext.view.View',
alias : 'widget.imageviewer',
initComponent: function()
{
    Ext.apply(this,{
        itemId : 'image-data-view',
        autoScroll : true,
        width : 600,
        store : getDataStore(),
        tpl : ['<div id="carouselDiv">',
                '<tpl for=".">',               // 1st loop
                '<span>{total}</span>',
                '<a href="#" onclick="clickNext({#})">Prev</a>',
                '<tpl for="images">',          // 2nd loop
                    '<div class="thumb-wrap">', // itemSelector of my choice
                        '<div class="thumb"><img src="{src}" title="{caption}"></div>',
                        '<span class="x-editable">{caption:htmlEncode}</span>',
                    '</div>',
                '</tpl>',
                '<div class="x-clear"></div>',
                '<a href="#" onclick="clickNext({#})">Next</a>',
                '</tpl>',
                '</div>'],
        multiSelect : true,
        trackOver : true,
        overItemCls : 'x-item-over',
        itemSelector : 'div.thumb-wrap',  // its not working
        emptyText : 'No images to display',
        listeners : {
            afterrender : function(current, eOpts) {
                current.getStore().load();
            },
            containerclick : function(current, e ,opts)
            {
                console.log(current.ownerCt);
            }
        }           
    });
    this.callParent(arguments);
  }
});
function clickNext(index)
{
    Ext.Msg.alert("Alert","Just a dummy Alert");
}
```

**JSON:**

```
{
    data: {
      total: 120,
      start: 0,
      end: 20,
      images: [{...},{...},{...}]
    }
}
```

**Store:**

```
Ext.define('ImageModel', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',      
    proxy : {
        type : 'ajax',
        url: '/images',
        noCache : true,
        reader : {
            type : 'json',
            totalProperty: 'total',
            rootProperty : 'data'
        }
    }
});
```

**StackTrace:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'internalId' of undefined ext-all.js:22
Ext.cmd.derive.updateIndexes ext-all.js:22
Ext.cmd.derive.refresh ext-all.js:22
Ext.cmd.derive.refresh ext-all.js:22
Ext.cmd.derive.refreshView ext-all.js:22
Ext.cmd.derive.onDataRefresh ext-all.js:22
Ext.cmd.derive.doFire ext-all.js:22
Ext.cmd.derive.fire ext-all.js:22
Ext.cmd.derive.doDispatchEvent ext-all.js:22
Ext.cmd.derive.dispatchEvent ext-all.js:22
Ext.cmd.derive.doFireEvent ext-all.js:22
a.doFireEvent ext-all.js:22
Ext.cmd.derive.fireEvent ext-all.js:22
Ext.cmd.derive.loadRecords ext-all.js:22
Ext.cmd.derive.onProxyLoad ext-all.js:22
Ext.cmd.derive.triggerCallbacks ext-all.js:22
Ext.cmd.derive.setCompleted ext-all.js:22
Ext.cmd.derive.setSuccessful ext-all.js:22
Ext.cmd.derive.process ext-all.js:22
Ext.cmd.derive.processResponse ext-all.js:22
(anonymous function) ext-all.js:22
Ext.apply.callback ext-all.js:22
Ext.cmd.derive.onComplete ext-all.js:22
Ext.cmd.derive.onStateChange ext-all.js:22
(anonymous function) ext-all.js:22
```

Whenever I am trying with `itemSelector: 'div.blabla'` its just go ahead without any problem in console.. indeed it do not work since there is no class as **blabla**.. so its kind of confusing stuff for me.. any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO you overdone that. You don't need 2 loops, because you return only one image array from server. So what is the point of that?

Only thing you should actually change is to add `total` to data provided for template. It is easier than creating two loops. You can do that for example in `collectData` method:

```
collectData: function(records, startIndex){
    var data = this.callParent(arguments);
    data.total = this.getStore().getTotalCount()
    return data;
}
```

Then your template can look like this:

```
tpl : [
    '<div id="carouselDiv">',
       '<span>{total}</span>',
       '<a href="#" onclick="clickNext({#})">Prev</a>',
       '<tpl for=".">',               // 1st loop
           '<div class="thumb-wrap">', // itemSelector of my choice
               '<div class="thumb"><img src="{src}" title="{caption}"></div>',
               '<span class="x-editable">{caption:htmlEncode}</span>',
           '</div>',
       '</tpl>',
       '<div class="x-clear"></div>',
       '<a href="#" onclick="clickNext({#})">Next</a>',
    '</div>'
]
```

Also you should correct `rootProperty` and change it to `images`.

Worging sample (without css): http://jsfiddle.net/Xf7N8/6/

Comment: Thanks @Lolo, but one thing I did not understood is, how `getTotalCount();` works ? if I removed `total` from json its counting array length otherwise it picks up property `total`.. !!  
and 2). what would happen if I have more than one array in json response, and if they are too complex such as array within another one etc.. Do I have to create separate Model for them ? or is it possible for `reader` to pick up desired node dynamically ?

Comment: You just described how `getTotalCount` works :) When you have server side pagination, than you send `totalCount` from server so JS now how many pages there are on server side. If you send everything stright away (without server pagination), than you don't need that. 
If you want to have more arrays in response, then you basically need to extend data View, because it not support that out of box. Hard to say what is required to customize view to handle hierarchical data. It can turn out that customizing tree would be easier.

Comment: How to access other properties then.. I mean e.g. `start`, `end` and other possible properties inside Xtemplate ?, I am sorry, if its annoying but understanding this taking bit of time

Comment: Add what you need inside `collectData`. Returned object is used via template. You can use `this.getStore().getProxy().getReader().rawData` to access `start` and `end` properties.

Comment: that's awesome... :) great ! but why ? can't I use in the straight forward way ? like I am choosing rootProperty as data and then iterating over its properties !! ?

Answer (score 1):

The point of the itemSelector is to map the DOM nodes to the records in the store. That means, what you wrap inside the itemSelector should encapsulate a single record:

```
itemSelector: '.person',
tpl: [
    'some markup',
    '<tpl for=".">,
        '<div class="person">{name}</div>',
    '</tpl>'
],
```

Everything about the person should be inside the `person` div.

Comment: I already did that but no avail.. if u see 2nd `<tpl for="images">` its for every single record inside images array. am I missing something ?

Comment: As I said above, it needs to map to records in the store. The store that you're looping over is in the outer loop, not the inner loop.

Comment: ok.. you mean to say the `rootProperty` of reader ? Pardon me as I am quite new in ExtJS related stuff.

Comment: No. The `<tpl for="."></tpl>` loop is looping over each record in your store. I think your data definitions are wrong. Your model has no fields declared. By the look of the data, the rootProperty should be `data.images`.